# What does さすがお尻マイスター mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, slang

When one of my girlfriend asked her friend, if he is in Osaka now, he said "yes, that's right" (in japanese) and then "さすがお尻マイスター".

I didn't understand it, but I didn't ask her or him back either. 
Now when I google it, さすが means "just what one would expect", お尻 is "butt" and マイスター is "Meister" in Katakana.

But what does the combination of さすが お尻 マイスター mean?

I don't even understand the direct translation: "Just what I / you would expect from butt master". Can someone help me or explain it to me?

Comment: Actually, マイスター is [Meister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meister) in katakana. ;) (マスター does exist as well...)

Comment: @Earthling: Oh yes, of course. But Meister is "master", so... :)

Comment: It doesn't sound like it means anything sensible to me - it's probably an 'in joke'.

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood it's a reference to some inside joke that he and she would understand. おしりマイスター isn't exactly standard fare in greetings between friends so you can assume that something that "out there" will have a special significance to those in the know.

If you find out why your (girl?)friend is the butt master feel free to let us know.

Comment: There are a number of Google results for "お尻マイスター", but after coming across an illustrated website about body fat reduction I'm not sure I want to find out...

Comment: I only see someone's twitter and a niconico page.. what else are you finding?

Comment: That number is [about 60](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E3%81%8A%E5%B0%BB%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%22&hl=ja&ei=o6rLUaTBCYmbiQLb54HwDw&start=60&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=624).

Comment: You asked: [美尻への道のり—田上様 with おしりマイスター中山](http://ameblo.jp/rejubenation-oubaitouri/entry-11553926499.html).

Answer (score 1):

"さすがお尻マイスター" = "さすが、あなたはお尻マイスターですね。"
That's why you are (called) a master of butt. or I knew! You ARE a master of butt!!

He loves butt too much. He cannot stop expressing his love to butt, and she knows that.
Maybe, he said something about butt, and she said "You ARE a MASTER of butt!!"

It may be a joke. It might be close to "There you go again!" laughing him.